# Compilation is getting failed due to error 157

Tags: android

Android resource compilation failed

> E:\VectorAssetDemo\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:157:
> error: invalid color.
> E:\VectorAssetDemo\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:
>
> error: file failed to compile.

I have tried nothing.

no debuggable process

I was trying to use vector asset in an `ImageView` and I was also trying to implement colors on them.

Comment: There is an invalid color

Comment: check your color.xml file

Comment: Attach your `color.xml` file here. Or attach `..\merged.dir\values\values.xml:157` line.

Comment: <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"

Answer (score 0):

A color in values.xml needs to follow this format.

```
<color name="theColorName">#000000</color>
```

Comment: I'm following same but when I build the app it starts showing me an error that the property is wrong.

Comment: The API level is 15.